# Is there a way to specify cursor (caret) position when defining template for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I would like to change default template for adding a new C# class in Visual Studio 2019.

So when you right click C# project and then go `Add new item -> Class` (or `Shift + Alft + C` keyboard shortcut) I get a new file with class. I'd like to add `public` access modifier by default for every class created. To do that I edited this file:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs`

I successfully and file now looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemrootname$
    {
      // initial cursor position should be here
    }
}
```

In addition I'd like to set default cursor (caret) position to the position between class' curly brackets (where I put comment) so that I can immediately start typing the code (without having to lift my hands off the keyboard just to grab the mouse to position the caret there). Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio? I know there is solution with ReSharper but I don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, I find that it is hard for us to set the cursor position by changing the class file directly.

However, If you are interested in the visual-studio extension, you can look at the following link to set the cursor position.

[Setting cursor position with Visual Studio Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137716/setting-cursor-position-with-visual-studio-extension)